# Set values for CharField in django admin model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model in django

```
class Process(models.Model):
       chemicals = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHEMICAL)
       high_temp = models.BooleanField()
       other_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REQ)
       flow = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I need to get the values of chemicals, high_temp(True/false) and requirements and display it as a string in flow field, which should be done dynamically once the user gives input to the three fields.

I tried using model property and overriding save method as follows but none worked out as expected.

```
@property
def flow(self):
     return self.chemicals+"-"+self.other_requirements

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.flow = self.chemicals+"-"+self.other_requirements
     super(Process, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is it possible to display the flow field value based on other inputs in django admin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If flow has to be computed dynamically, you don't need to save "flow" to the databse, remove the flow field definition and just keep the property definition. You should also get rid of your save method override.

Also return a string from your property you should probably use

```
return "%s-%s-%s" % (self.chemicals, self.high_temp, self.other_requirements)
```

which will yield less unexpected results.

If you want to display the flow property in admin form, add it to your fieldsets definition as well as to your readonly_fields definition.

Comment: it throws Field Error Exception type "Unknown field(s) (flow) specified for Process"

Answer (score 0):

you can't have an attribute `flow = models.CharField(max_length=100)` and a method with the same name.

You need to delete one of these. Which one? If you have flow data already stored in 3 other fields then storing it in a separate field would be redundant. I think you should drop the field entirely and use the method.

```
class Process(models.Model):
    chemicals = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHEMICAL)
    high_temp = models.BooleanField()
    other_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=REQ)

    def flow(self):
        if self.chemicals and self.high_temp and self.other_requirements:
            return '{}-{}-{}'.format(self.chemicals, self.high_temp, self.other_requirements)
        else:
            return None
```

Note that I'm using string `.format` method which is a recommended way to build strings. Don't plus them together anymore.

EDIT: you can project the method on `list_display`, simply put it inside the tuple

```
class ProcessAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('chemicals', 'high_temp', 'other_requirements', 'flow')
    ...
```